# How to import heavy module without freezing pyqt ui?

Tags: python, module, pyqt

i have this heavy module, but when i import it , it freezes my pyqt ui, the ui pop up after the importing is done.

i've tried

```py
def background_imports():
    # how do i put zz into global namespace ?
    import xxx.yy as zz

thread = threading.Thread(target=background_imports)
thread.setDaemon(True)
thread.start()
```

it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Your module is loaded in different thread namespace, so it can't be accessed from your main thread.

One option is look for [apipkg helper module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/apipkg), which can help you postpone import up to the moment module is needed for the first time.

Other is return imported module from your thread, but I am not sure whether it will have some speed-ups (as a pickled version of module will be returned, i.e. it will be unpickled in your main thread), or is error prone (never did try or even test):

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def background_imports():
    import numpy as np
    return np

pool = ThreadPool(processes=1)

async_result = pool.apply_async(background_imports) 
np = async_result.get(3)
print np.mean(1)
# 1.0
```